# In development React re-mounts every component, but why does the screen only displays the UI snapshot of one component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this [React challenge](https://codesandbox.io/s/sv75dd?file=/Counter.js&utm_medium=sandpack) the UI of DOM, is only visible on the screen once, but due to being in development, React re-mounts the Counter component and that makes the `setInterval` function to run twice ( if that's not the case then why is it that `setInterval` is running twice after each render? ). Why does the UI not conform the logic?

Answer (score 0):

Since React version 18, strict mode was introduced, to help us avoid unsafe lifecycle. You can read more here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

The proper way to write this useEffect would be to clear the interval on unmount:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function onTick() {
      setCount(c => c + 1);
    }

    const interval = setInterval(onTick, 1000);
  
    return () => clearInterval(interval)


  }, []);
```

Comment: Definitely, but why with the mentioned code (the one by me), we aren't getting DOM updated with two components?